# Use Same Variable In Multiple View Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I have two colour variables:

```
var blue = UIColor(red:0.08, green:0.49, blue:0.49, alpha:1.0)
var red = UIColor(red:0.61, green:0.12, blue:0.20, alpha:1.0)
```

I have declared these variables in my `EntryViewController`, however, I also need to use them in my other `ViewControllers`. I was wondering if it were possible to use the same variables in multiple `ViewControllers`? I already know about passing data with segues, but I was wondering if there were a way to maybe declare the colours in their own class and subclass my `ViewControllers` with this class. Thank you.

Comment: Why assign `UIColor()`, if you're going to immediately overwrite it with `UIColor(red:0.08, green:0.49, blue:0.49, alpha:1.0)`?

Comment: I thought I needed to make it like that to change it later in my code, I have updated the code with your suggestion. Thankyou

Comment: Why would you change the colour blue? That's a pretty consistent colour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach here is to create an `extension` on `UIColor`. You can then make them global to your module.

```
extension UIColor {
    static var myRed: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red:0.61, green:0.12, blue:0.20, alpha:1.0)
    }
    static var myBlue: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 0.08, green: 0.49, blue: 0.49, alpha:1.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new to programming. Would you mind further explaining this to me?

Comment: `UIColor` is immutable. You can use one shared instance instead of creating a new instance for every caller

Comment: @M.I Please read the Swift language guide. Stack overflow isn't an alternative to learning the language. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Comment: I am familiar with the Swift language; my language pertains more to Xcode and its functionalities than the Swift language.

Comment: @M.I Are you sure? Extensions, static members, computed properties, and enums are all pretty basic parts of Swift...

Answer (score 1):

You could make these global variables, but that's frowned upon because it pollutes the global name space. Instead, you can make these static members of a new type. A class or struct would work, but typically, an `enum` is used for this, just to ensure that no instances of the type can be made.

```
enum Colors {
    static let blue = UIColor(red: 0.08, green: 0.49, blue: 0.49)
    static let red = UIColor(red: 0.61, green: 0.12, blue: 0.20)
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, would you mind further explaining this to me? In specifically where I would declare it and how I would call it in my other `ViewControllers`?